# Getting the min / max value from a list object that has multiple attributes

Tags: java, android, list, sorting

If I have objects of List where each object has different values for attributes like getDistance(), getPrice(), getRating(), etc. How should I do it?

I've tried overriding compareTo but it only can sort one attribute.

I am trying to do the simple additive weighting method, where I have to get the min / max value of each attribute and perform calculations with it.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If you have a list of objects that you want to sort using a specific algorithm, then you can implement your own Comparator and use the Collection.sort() method to sort the list. Lets say you have a class called **Container** that is the object you want to compare, it has 3 properties; distance, price and rating. You would implement your custom comparator of type Container and define the specific algorithm that checks 2 Container objects. I've written an example below, where the comparative adds the values of all 3 properties and them divides them by 3 (the divide by 3 is unnecessary in this example, but i kept it in there to show that you can make the equation more complex if needed), it then compares which one is lower and returns an integer indicating that fact.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.List;

class Container {
    private double distance;
    private double price;
    private double rating;

    public Container(double distance, double price, double rating) {
        this.distance = distance;
        this.price = price;
        this.rating = rating;
    }

    public double getDistance() {
        return distance;
    }
    public void setDistance(double distance) {
        this.distance = distance;
    }
    public double getPrice() {
        return price;
    }
    public void setPrice(double price) {
        this.price = price;
    }
    public double getRating() {
        return rating;
    }
    public void setRating(double rating) {
        this.rating = rating;
    }
}

class CustomComparator implements Comparator<Container> {

    @Override
    public int compare(Container o1, Container o2) {
        double avgVal1 = (o1.getDistance()+o1.getPrice()+o1.getRating())/3; 
        double avgVal2 = (o2.getDistance()+o2.getPrice()+o2.getRating())/3;
        return avgVal1 < avgVal2 ? -1 : 1;
    }
}

public class CompareTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Container> containerList = new ArrayList<Container>(4);
        containerList.add(new Container(2.0, 3.0, 6.0));
        containerList.add(new Container(1.0, 1.0, 1.0));
        containerList.add(new Container(6.2, 0.0, 0.0));
        containerList.add(new Container(0.0, 3.2, 1.5));
        Collections.sort(containerList, new CustomComparator());
        for(int idx=0; idx<containerList.size(); idx++){
            System.out.println("Distance:" + containerList.get(idx).getDistance() +
                               "\tPrice:" + containerList.get(idx).getPrice() +
                               "\tRating:"  + containerList.get(idx).getRating());
        }
    }
}
```

After you run main(), it'll create a list of Container object in no particular order, then sorts them using the custom comparator and then prints it out, this is the output:

```
Distance:1.0    Price:1.0   Rating:1.0
Distance:0.0    Price:3.2   Rating:1.5
Distance:6.2    Price:0.0   Rating:0.0
Distance:2.0    Price:3.0   Rating:6.0
```

You can see here that the list got sorted from lowest to highest based on all the properties in Container.